# Run javascript function on page reload but dont show onbeforeunload event popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I want disconect the user on page reload but dont want to show this popup
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trqZn.png)

Here is my code ==>

```
useEffect(()=>{

const disconnect = (event) => {
  event?.preventDefault();
  socketRef.current.disconnect();
  return undefined;
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', disconnect);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload',disconnect);
}

},[navigate])
```

Comment: You can use 
window.addEventListener('unload', () => {})

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the browser from showing the confirmation alert, do not return anything from the beforeunload event handler. Browsers often interpret a return value from this event as a signal to show the confirmation dialog.
More information on the beforeunload event can be found here: [beforeload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
        socket.disconnect();
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
        socket.disconnect();
    };
}, [socket]);
```